# How to cascade dropdown list based on list values

Tags: jquery, html

Below are two dropdown lists to be cascaded based on their option values

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#s1").change(function(){
        $("#s2").val($("#s1").val())
    });
});
```

```html
<select id="s1">
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
    <option value="4">d</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
    <option value="1">a2</option>
    <option value="1">a3</option>
    <option value="2">b2</option>
    <option value="2">b3</option>
    <option value="3">c2</option>
    <option value="3">c3</option>
    <option value="4">d2</option>
    <option value="4">d3</option>
</select>
```

All the options are visible in `$("#s2")` irrespective of option selected in the element `$("#s1")`.

Comment: so what is your question ?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
         $("#s1").change(function(){
            //$("#s2").val($("#s1").val())
            var val=$("#s1").val();

            $("#s2 option").each(function(){
                if($(this).val()!=val)
                {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
            $("#s2").val($("#s1").val());


        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#s1").change(function () {
        $("#s2 option").hide();
        $("#s2 option[value="+$("#s1").val()+"]").show();
        $("#s2").val($("#s1").val());
    }).trigger("change");
});
```

<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/xfv5j3ec/)</kbd>

Comment: Works perfect too.. Thanks Banana .trigger("change") is a good learning point.